# Power line communication over 220V 50Hz main line

Tags: power-line-communication

I want to make a device to send and receive data using the main power line, and I want it to be compatible with the X10 protocol, but i have no resource on the circuit and I don't know how to inject the data to the main or receive it.

I know about the protocol and the theory, but I have nothing practical to begin with, so any circuit schematic or basic how to will be of great help for me to get a kick start.

I am planning to make a device around AVR micro controllers that can send and receive data over power line with the X10 protocol.

What I would like to know about at this point is how I can inject my data to the main line.

Edit: creating a 120kHz is easy, but transferring/inducting/injecting it to the main line is the problem. I don't know how to do it. what is the right way to do it? I thinks it's called coupling but there are many kinds of coupling and i don't know which one to use.

Comment: why the down vote?

Comment: Have you looked for techniques that are used?

Comment: I cant find any resource I told you, there are plenty of theoretical stuff but none of them actually tells you how to do it. I would love to find some! can you show me some?

Comment: @FarzadBekran Have you seen the many questions listed as related to this? [1](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1654/injecting-a-communication-signal-over-dc-power-supply-lines?rq=1) [2](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3663/power-line-communication-principles?rq=1) [3](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/4508/dc-power-line-communications?rq=1) [4](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/5680/how-do-these-powerline-networking-adapters-work?rq=1)

Comment: This question is too broad. Injecting your data on the power line involves the whole of electrical engineering. What part is giving you trouble?

Comment: @PhilFrost suppose I want to put a 1 on the line and receive it on the other side, the actual "put a 1 on the line" part is where I need help with. I know where and when to do it, when the wave hits 0, inject your data on the wave, but how?

Comment: @FarzadBekran "inject your data" isn't very precise language. "How does X10 encode data?" would be a more specific question, but perhaps not a good one, since surely there are resources that already explain this.

Comment: @PhilFrost the problem is not the x10, this is from wiki: `In the 60 Hz AC current flow, a bit value of one is represented by a 1 millisecond burst of 120 kHz at the zero crossing point (nominally 0°, but within 200 microseconds of the zero crossing point), immediately followed by the absence of a pulse. A zero value is represented by the absence of 120 kHz at the zero crossing point (pulse), immediately followed by the presence of a pulse. All messages are sent twice to reduce false signaling.` the problem is how to burst that 120kHz to the line

Comment: @FarzadBekran ok, so what part of that don't you understand? Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: @PhilFrost Edited

Answer (score 2):

Here, let me Google that for you...  Doing a simple search for "X10 circuit" brought up about 3.5 million hits.  One of the first ones is this [application note from Microchip on X10 interfacing](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/appnotes/00236a.pdf).  Enjoy.

Comment: lol I totally love this: `You don't have permission to access "http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/appnotes/00236a.pdf" on this server.

Reference #18.7d3ff5cc.1358451338.ce6bcf88 `

Comment: @FarzadBekran works for me. Company / national firewall?

Comment: Living in Iran has it's consequences ;)

Comment: @FarzadBekran Just use the quickview from google. This usually bypasses the firewall. Under the link name look for the word cached or quickview and it will open it through google.

Comment: @GustavoLitovsky there is no cache or anything, just a small preview

Comment: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BzQy7VqoEbCraTd3YVZzcFBVaTg/edit donwload it from here if you can't see it